# Unity rigidbody - jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I would like to ask you for help.

I am using the new Unity Input system and I am having a trouble to make jump working.

I need to reset an animation of jumping back to idle/walking as well as set hasPlayerJumped variable to false.

Would any of you have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

The TryMove(...) is called from FixedUpdate().

```
public bool TryMove(bool isPlayerGrounded)
    {

        Vector3 _moveVector = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(playerMovementInput.x, 0f, playerMovementInput.y)) * movementSpeed;
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector3(_moveVector.x, playerBody.velocity.y, _moveVector.z);
        playerAnimator.SetFloat("forwardSpeed", playerBody.velocity.normalized.magnitude);

        // Jump
        TryToJump(isPlayerGrounded);
        return true;
    }

    private void TryToJump(bool isPlayerGrounded)
    {
        if (isPlayerGrounded && hasPlayerJumped)
        {
            playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            playerAnimator.SetBool("hasJumped", true);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the new Input System.

```
    private void Start()
    {
        InitControlsCallbacks();
    }

    private void InitControlsCallbacks()
    {
        Controls.Player.Move.performed += ctx => StartMoving(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        Controls.Player.Move.canceled += ctx => CancelMovement();
        Controls.Player.Jump.performed += ctx => SetJump();
    }

    private void StartMoving(Vector2 _movementVector)
    {
        playerMovementInput = _movementVector;
        isPlayerMooving = true;
    }
    private void CancelMovement()
    {
        playerMovementInput = Vector2.zero;
        isPlayerMooving = false;
    }

    private void SetJump()
    {
        hasPlayerJumped = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor a little bit like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody playerBody;
    public Animator playerAnimator;
    public float jumpForce = 5f;
    public float movementSpeed = 10f;

    private bool isGrounded = false;
    private bool hasPlayerJumped = false;
    private bool isPlayerMoving = false;

    private Vector2 playerMovementInput;

    private void Start()
    {
        InitControlsCallbacks();
    }

    private void InitControlsCallbacks()
    {
        Controls.Player.Move.performed += ctx => StartMoving(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        Controls.Player.Move.canceled += ctx => CancelMovement();
        Controls.Player.Jump.performed += ctx => SetJump();
    }

    private void StartMoving(Vector2 _movementVector)
    {
        playerMovementInput = _movementVector;
        isPlayerMoving = true;
    }
    private void CancelMovement()
    {
        playerMovementInput = Vector2.zero;
        isPlayerMoving = false;
    }

    private void SetJump()
    {
        // Jump
        TryToJump(isGrounded);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        TryMove(isGrounded);
    }

    public bool TryMove(bool isPlayerGrounded)
    {
        if (hasPlayerJumped)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Vector3 _moveVector = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(playerMovementInput.x, 0f, playerMovementInput.y)) * movementSpeed;
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector3(_moveVector.x, playerBody.velocity.y, _moveVector.z);
        playerAnimator.SetFloat("forwardSpeed", playerBody.velocity.normalized.magnitude);

        return true;
    }

    private void TryToJump(bool isPlayerGrounded)
    {
        if (isPlayerGrounded && !hasPlayerJumped)
        {
            playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            playerAnimator.SetBool("hasJumped", true);

            hasPlayerJumped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it yet, since I'd need to create the new Unity InputSystem along with Controls and all the variables you mention.

Also note that `isGrounded` variable must be set using the collider (or **Rigidbody**) when it touches the ground.

Let me know if you find any issues.